# Formula field for checking isdeleted or not

Tags: formula-field, isdeleted

I have a scenario to check the record isDeleted or not and show it in a field, is there any way to do it not having SOQL

Comment: the standard UI can't show deleted records; but API clients can and they already have access to `IsDeleted` checkbox field

Answer (score 0):

I find this confusing because I don't understand where you would be viewing the record to see the deleted flag you want to create. I'm not sure if this is something you really want to do.

However the answer to your question is yes, it is possible without SOQL. You could create a checkbox field on your record and a flow triggered on before record delete. When the flow runs it can mark your new field as true. You can then use this field in whatever formula you like. You would also need another flow triggered on undelete to mark your field as false.